# Show that $\frac{1}{x^x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and find its integral on this range.

Tags: integration, analysis, functions, summation, continuity

The question is as follows:

Show that 
$\frac{1}{x^x}$ is continuous on $[0,1]$, and that its integral on this range is equal  to $\sum\frac{1}{n^n}$ from $n=1$ to $n=\infty$.

The question also provides the following hint:

Write $\frac{1}{x^x} = \sum\frac{(-xlogx)^n}{n!}$ from $n=0$ to $n= \infty$.

Thanks so much for any help! :)

Comment: For you to prove that $1/x^x$ is continuous on the *closed* interval $[0, 1]$, you must be given the value at $0$ separately as $x^x$ does not make sense for $x = 0$.

Comment: That is [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream) – there are a lot of Q&A's around it: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Sophomore%27s+dream

Comment: For the continuity at $x=0$, see for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769644/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246540/42969.

Comment: Thanks everyone!